# The set $\mathbb R$ is an homogeneous space with this specific topology

Tags: general-topology, functions

A space $X$ is homogeneous if for every $x,y\in X$, there is an homeomorphism $h\colon X\to X$ such that $h(x)=y$.

Let $\mathbb R$ be a topological space with the next basis: $$\{ (a,b)\cup A\colon a,b\in\mathbb R, a<b\textrm{ and }A\subset\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q\} $$ Establish whether $\mathbb R$ is an homogeneous space with this topology.

I would really appreciate any hint for this one. I feel lost.

help

Comment: I added a solution, if you only wanted a hint: Assume that $h\colon \mathbb{R}\cong \mathbb{R}$ is a homeomorphism such that it maps a rational number to an irrational number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By contradiction, let $h\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be an **open function** s.t. $h(\pi)=0$.

If $\{0\}$ is open, then $\{0\}=\bigcup_{\alpha\in\mathscr{A}}(a_\alpha,b_\alpha)\cup A_\alpha$
for some $\{a_\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\mid \alpha\in\mathscr{A}\}$, $\{b_\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\mid \alpha\in\mathscr{A}\}$, and $\{A_\alpha\in\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})\mid \alpha\in\mathscr{A}\}$ with $a_\alpha<b_\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in\mathscr{A}$. Since $0\in \bigcup_{\alpha\in\mathscr{A}}(a_\alpha,b_\alpha)\cup A_\alpha$, there exists some $\beta\in \mathscr{A}$ s.t. $0\in (a_\beta,b_\beta)\cup A_\beta$ and, since $A_\beta$ contains only irrationals, $0\in (a_\beta,b_\beta)\subseteq\bigcup_{\alpha\in\mathscr{A}}(a_\alpha,b_\alpha)\cup A_\alpha=\{0\}$ and $(a_\beta,b_\beta)\subseteq \{0\}$. We conclude that $\{0\}$ is not open.

We have that $h(\{\pi\})=\{0\}$ must be open since $\pi$ is irrational and $h$ is open, since $\{0\}$ is not open, a contradiction is reached and $\mathbb{R}$ is not homogeneous with this topology $\square$.

Note that if we relax the definition of homogeneity by using open functions instead of homeomorphisms, $\mathbb{R}$ would still not be homogeneous (as the proof shows).